# Ito Integration of $\int_0^TB_t\,d(B_t)^2$?

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I am trying to solve the given integral with Brownian motion
$$
\int_{i=0}^T B_t\,d(B_t)^2
$$
I have solved so far like this,
$$
\int_{i=0}^T B_t\,d(B_t)^2 = \sum_{0}^T B_t(B_{t+1} - B_t)^2
$$
We can re-write $B_t$ as,
$$
B_t =  \frac{1}{2}(B_{t+1} + B_t) - \frac{1}{2}(B_{t+1} - B_t)
$$
Substituting,
$$
\sum_{0}^T B_t(B_{t+1} - B_t)^2 = \sum_{0}^T (\frac{1}{2}(B_{t+1} + B_t) - \frac{1}{2}(B_{t+1} - B_t))(B_{t+1} - B_t)^2
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{0}^T(B_{t+1} + B_t)(B_{t+1} - B_t)^2 - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{0}^T(B_{t+1} - B_t)(B_{t+1} - B_t)^2
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{0}^T (B_{t+1} + B_t)(B_{t+1} - B_t)(B_{t+1} - B_t) - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{0}^T(B_{t+1} - B_t)^3
$$
$$
= \underbrace {\frac{1}{2}\sum_{0}^T (B_{t+1}^2 - B_t^2)(B_{t+1} - B_t)}_{\text{1st part}} - \underbrace{ \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^T(dB)^3}_{\text{2nd part}}
$$
Here is where the problem arises, 
 In the 2nd part,

 we know that $dBt^2 = dt$, but what would be $dBt^3$ 
Does it go towards 0?

In the first part, we know that, 
$\int{(B_{t+1}^2 - B_t^2)} = Bt^2$ but what happends with the extra term - $\int{(B_{t+1} - B_t)}$

Can anyone please help me out??

Comment: note that $$d(B_t)^2 = 2B_t\,dB_t + dt
$$ with respect to the Ito derivative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you follow the hint by @Khosrotash you don't need $(dB_t)^3\,:$
From
$$
d(B_t)^2=2B_t\,dB_t+dt\,,\quad\text{ and }\quad d(B_t)^3=3B_t^2\,dB_t+3B_t\,dt
$$
your integral becomes
\begin{align}
&\textstyle\int_0^TB_t\,d(B_t)^2=\textstyle\int_0^T2B_t^2\,dB_t+\int_0^TB_t\,dt\\[2mm]
&=\textstyle\frac{2}{3}B_T^3-\int_0^TB_t\,dt\,.
\end{align}
If we want we can write the last term as
$$
\textstyle\int_0^TB_t\,dt=\int_0^T(T-t)\,dB_t\,.
$$

Comment: Thank You so much. I got a same solution following the pdf [here](https://personal.ntu.edu.sg/nprivault/MA5182/brownian-motion-stochastic-calculus.pdf). @Khosrotash Thank You for your help.